# Creating a Gallery page for a website

Tags: asp.net, layout, gallery

I want to create a page that looks similar to this one: http://aqua-restaurant.com/photos

Page Layout:

```
[Heading 1]

[photo] [photo] [photo]
[photo] [photo] [photo]
[photo] [photo] [photo]

[Heading 2]

[photo] [photo] [photo]
[photo] [photo] [photo]
[photo] [photo] [photo]
```

etc.

I am using ASP.NET.
Does anyone know of a tutorial/template on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should Google for 'asp.net photo gallery':
http://geekswithblogs.net/omtalsania7/archive/2012/12/27/how-to-create-an-image-grid-with-asp.net-44.5-using.aspx

You could put a counter in the template or code to break up the galleries with 9 images.

Comment: Thanks for your effort!